# Native Date Picker not allowing to change month & year

Tags: javascript, input, datepicker

I have this problem only in **Firefox Android Browser APP** that too in Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 N8000  (I tried in other phones & tabs it works).

A simple **input type = "date"** is not allowing me to change month & year.It is only allowing me to select from current month.

I know I could use modernizr to fallback to jquery ui if browser does not have a datepicker. but in this case browser supports datepicker
How do I manage such things ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
<body>
Enter Date here : <br> 
<input type="date" />
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks In Advance..

Answer (score 0):

please do not use html5 input type cause it is not support all browser . Try to solve this problem using jquery. I think this plugin help you to solve this issue any type of browser :

**https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/**